# Laravel order by price with condition special price

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have table with next columns (price, special_price, is_special).

```
+-------+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
| id    | price |  special_price  | is_special   | qty      |
+-------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+
| 1     | 100   |    null         | 0            |  5       |
| 2     | 120   |    99           | 1            |  0       |
| 3     | 300   |    null         | 0            |  1       |
| 4     | 400   |    350          | 1            |  10      |
| 5     | 75    |    69           | 1            |  0       |
| 6     | 145   |    135          | 0            |  1       |
+-------+-------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
```

I want to get products ordered by 'price' with condition, if 'is_special' column is true then select 'special_price' column.

I want to get next result.

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| id    | price     |  special_price  | is_special   | qty          |
+-------+-----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| 5     | 75        |    69           | 1            |  0           |
| 2     | 120       |    99           | 1            |  0           |
| 1     | 100       |    null         | 0            |  5           |
| 6     | 145       |    135          | 0            |  1           |
| 3     | 300       |    null         | 0            |  1           |
| 4     | 400       |    350          | 1            |  10          |
+-------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

On raw SQL it's looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM products
ORDER BY IF(is_special=0, price, special_price ) ASC;
```

I using Laravel and want to ordered and get query builder in result.

For example I did it with virtual attributes

```
/**
 * Get current price
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function getCurrentPriceAttribute()
 {
     return $this->is_special ? $this->special_price : $this->price;
 }
```

And sorted collection `$products->sortBy('current_price')`  but in this time I want to get query builder in result. 
Query builder not working with virtual attributes.

I'm trying to multiple sorting by two columns 'price' and 'qty'

```
$query = Product::query();

$query->orderByRaw("if(is_special=0, price, special_price) " . request('price', 'ASC'));
$query->orderBy('qty', request('qty', 'DESC'));

$query->get();
```

I have 2 filter 'Quantity' and 'Price'.

In this multiple ordering I want to get products ordering by price, then all products ordering by 'qty'. 
Products with qty == 0, need to be next after all products with qty > 0.

Help me, please.

Comment: post your query too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The First Problem

Query-Builder has no accessors, you need to select it out:

```php
DB::table('products')
   ->select('*')
   ->addSelect(DB::raw('IF(is_special=0, price, special_price ) AS current_price'))
   ->orderBy('current_price')
   ->get();
```

**PS**:Recommend to sort in database, think about if you have `paginate` on products, it will sort only on the one page's datas when it return that page.

---

### The second problem:

1. `qty > 0` AS 1, and `qty = 0` AS 0, then order them DESC:
2. Order by `price` with request
3. Order by `qty` with request

So the products will put the `qty > 0` before `qty = 0`, and the records that `qty > 0` will ordering by price, then all products ordering by `qty`; and the records that `qty = 0` will ordering by price, then all products ordering by `qty` too:

```php
$query = Product::query();
$query->orderBy(DB::raw(IF('qty > 0, 1, 0')), 'DESC');
$query->orderBy(DB::raw("IF(is_special=0, price, special_price)"), request('price', 'ASC'));
$query->orderBy('qty', request('qty', 'DESC'));
$query->get();
```

**PS**: `orderByRaw("if(is_special=0, price, special_price) " . request('price', 'ASC')` will be attack easily by **SQL-Injection**. Change to `orderBy(DB::raw("IF(is_special=0, price, special_price)"), request('price', 'ASC'))`

Comment: Thank a lot for you help.
I try you code, but qty ordering `$query->orderBy('qty', request('qty', 'DESC'));`  not working with request. I added request to qty ordering and it's working fine.
`$query->orderBy(DB::raw("IF(qty > 0, 1, 0)"), request('qty', 'DESC'));
$query->orderBy(DB::raw("IF(is_special = 0, price, special_price)"), request('price', 'ASC'));`
This one working fine, but i can't split this 2 filters. I want to create 2 independent methods.

Comment: @tosky I try it, it works fine. if the records that `qty > 0` and the prices are equal, they will be ordered by qty. can u tell me what's wrong with the result?

Comment: all working fine. You really helped me, thank you very much!